# Truncate and insert issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a script which has a big database so to decrease load i built a table which contain a data that is updated every minute(CRON PHP FILE).So it works just fine but i am having right now an issue.
The code I am using:

```
$conn->query("TRUNCATE tempo");
 $conn->query("INSERT INTO ....");
```

and the php file i get the data from the tempo table the problem right now is that when php runs every minute there is a short delay like 1 second between data delete and data insert so in this 1 second the table tempo is empty so every minute i have 1second in which the website just return 0 data (because of the delay). How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a transaction. but this sounds like a job that's better suited for redis.

Comment: Truncate table causes an implicit commit, so you cannot wrap this into a single transaction.

Comment: @Shadow hm, yes, missed that

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot have any downtime in accessing the data, then have 2 tables with identical structure, I'll refer to them as `table_A` and `table_B`. At any time, only one of them should be "live", meaning one will serve all requests for the data. Let's say it is table_A at the moment.

When you do the import from the cron, then truncate table_B and insert the data into table_B. When the insertion into table_B is done, then mark table_B as the live one and the next import's target should be table_A.

This way you are not going to have any downtime accessing your data.

Comment: If this is not possible to do (it's the only way of having no downtime I can think of), to reduce data delay you can try the following:
Insert everything into an special insert table (same structure as tempo). Then truncate tempo and insert everyhting from the special table into tempo. Depending on the number of rows that should be considerable faster, because everyhing happens directly on the server (INSERT INTO tempo SELECT * FROM tempo_special_import;).